# How to differentiate different Collection in java?

Tags: java, collections

Please explain how different collection are used under different scenario.

By this I mean to say how can I differentiate when to use a `List`, a `Set` or a `Map` interface.

Please provide some links to examples that can provide a clear explanation.

Also

```
    if insertion order is preserved then we should go for List.
    if insertion order is not preserved then we should go for Set.
```

What does "insertion order is preserved" means?

Comment: Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html

Comment: Generally 

List - Preserves order and allows duplicate.

Set -  Prevents duplicate and insertion order is not preserved, But you can have linkedHashSet to preserve order.

Map - When you have a key value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Insertion order**

Insertion order is preserving the order in which you have inserted the data.

For example you have inserted data {1,2,3,4,5}

Set returns something like {2,3,1,4,5}
while list returns {1,2,3,4,5} .//It preserves the order of insertion

**When to use List, Set and Map in Java**

1) If you need to access elements frequently by using index, then List is a way to go. Its implementation e.g. ArrayList provides faster access if you know index.

2) If you want to store elements and want them to maintain an order on which they are inserted into collection then go for List again, as List is an ordered collection and maintain insertion order.

3) If you want to create collection of unique elements and don't want any duplicate then choose any Set implementation e.g. HashSet, LinkedHashSet or TreeSet. All Set implementation follow there general contract e.g. uniqueness but also add addition feature e.g. TreeSet is a SortedSet and elements stored on TreeSet can be sorted by using Comparator or Comparable in Java. LinkedHashSet also maintains insertion order.

4) If you store data in form of key and value then Map is the way to go. You can choose from Hashtable, HashMap, TreeMap based upon your subsequent need.

You will find some more useful info at http://java67.blogspot.com/2013/01/difference-between-set-list-and-map-in-java.html